# impossible Cast between interfaces

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, generics, casting

I have an strange error, I have this classes:

**AbstractRepository**

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface abstractRepository<T extends someEntity,ID>  extends JpaRepository<T, ID>{
```

**CustomRepository**

```
@Repository
public interface customRepository extends abstractRepository<classThatExtendSomeEntity, Integer> {
```

**AbstractService**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public abstract class AbstractService<Entity extends someEntity, DTO extends someDTO>  
implements ComboWithSubproductsService<DTO>{
    
    protected AbstractRepository<Entity,Long> genericRepository;

    @Autowired
    public AbstractService(AbstractRepository<Entity, Long> repository) {
        super();
        this.genericRepository = repository;
    }
}
```

**CustomService**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class customServiceImpl extends abstractService<classThatExtendSomeClass, classThatExtendsSomeDTO> implements customService{
  
    private CustomRepository repository;

    public customServiceImpl (customRepository repository) {
        super(repository); //ERROR: the constructor AbstractRepository(customRepository) is undefined
    }
}
```

This are my main class, my error is in customService class because I don't know why I can't do a upcast customRepository to AbstractRepository when customRepository extends abstractRepository.
I am absolutly blocked whit this error, unti I know, it is always possible cast subclass to superclass. I don't know how solve this error.

Thanks for your time and sorry for my english, it is not my native languaje.

Comment: `customService` can only extend `abstractService<classThatExtendSomeEntity, Integer>`, it looks like.

Comment: `CustomRepository` uses `Integer` as the id class, but the `genericRepository` field uses `Long`.  These should be the same.

Comment: I feel me very stupid, i have spent 2 hour without seen the error, you are right @DawoodibnKareem, that was the error

Comment: Generally, Java is case sensitive. You have to be consistent in your use of upper case and lower case letters.

Comment: the Problem was not by case sensitive reason, the problem was that in one case we used Integer and in other Long.